# log4net AdoNetAppender Npgsql throws 42601: syntax error at or near ":"

Tags: c#, postgresql, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I got a problem trying to write my log4net logs to Postgres Database. 
.NET 4.6.2 project, PostgreSQL 11, Npgsql 4.0.7

My config:

```
<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="AdoNetAppender_Postgres" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <connectionType value="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql" />
     <connectionStringName value="MyRepoConnectionString" />
     <commandText value="INSERT INTO public.tbl_smg_log (datetime,thread,log_level,logger,message,cretariafields,exception,computerip,processid,appid,projectid) 
VALUES ('2019/05/22 16:59:04.767',:thread,'INFO','DOP.Infra.Classes.Log.TWLogger','Category=Debug,Priority=10','CriteriaFields','','169.254.90.84',22000,1,null)"/>
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <lossy value="false" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
</appender>
```

Executing this I have an internal log4net exception:

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception while writing to database
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: syntax error at or near ":"
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

When I change `:thread` to some constant value, like

```
<commandText value="INSERT INTO public.tbl_smg_log (datetime,thread,log_level,logger,message,cretariafields,exception,computerip,processid,appid,projectid) 
VALUES ('2019/05/22 16:59:04.767','somevalue','INFO','DOP.Infra.Classes.Log.TWLogger','Category=Debug,Priority=10','CriteriaFields','','169.254.90.84',22000,1,null)"/>
```

everything works good. 
I've tried to replace `:thread` with `@thread` and got other exception:

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception while writing to database
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column "thread" does not exist
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
```

`RollingFileAppender` using `%thread` is also works good. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Change in the definition for the parameter the attribute value to _value=:thread_

Comment: you mean like ```<parameterName value=":thread" />```? Nothing changed

Comment: Found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-538 What log4net version are you using ?

Comment: 2.0.8. More than 2 years of discussion, and no changes. I'm confused

Comment: `column "thread" does not exist` do you have that column in your database table `tbl_smg_log`?

Comment: I have an alternative that works for this it is currently up for pull request https://github.com/microknights/Log4NetAdoNetAppender/pull/18